# apply style on Bootstrap twitter grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I try to understand how is working bootstrap twitter. Could you told me what's the best way to set another color on TEXT2 only when grid system is on "col-xs-*" ?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-4">
        <span>TEXT1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-8">
        <span>TEXT2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wVX65/

PS: sorry for my english...

Answer (score 0):

.col-xs applies to screens < 768px. To apply the colour of text2 when the screen is < 768px. you could make use of media queries in your css. For example -

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px){
   /* Change text colour */

    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZp5V/)

Comment: it's not possible to make something like this (with a plugin or anything else) ? 

.col-xs{color:red}

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible to make something like this (with a plugin or anything else) ?

```
.col-xs{color:red}
```